# How to generate async/await version with gRPC Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, grpc, grpc-swift

We are currently generating swift code with gRPC.

```
protoc <proto_path> --grpc-swift_opt=Client=true,Server=false 
                    --grpc-swift_out=. 
                    --swift_opt=Visibility=Public
```

We are looking to migrate to async-await. Any idea, what argument we have to pass to generate async-await version code?

Thank you in advance

Comment: See forum article re experimental support for async-await: https://forums.swift.org/t/grpc-swift-async-await-support/52134